# In equal comparison of a literal value does the order of operands matter?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I am accustomed to write the code as(just an example)

```
Request.QueryString["xxxx"] != null
```

Recently someone said that

```
null != Request.QueryString["xxxx"]
```

gives a better performance.

I am curious to know as whether it actually brings any difference or not and if so how?

Note~ The above is just an example. To be generically speaking

Whether

```
Constant [Operator] Actual Value (e.g. 1 == Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text))
```

is better than

```
Actual Value [Operator] Constant (e.g. Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) == 1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true in general. Comparison operators need to evaluate both their sides so there is no gain in putting constants on the left. But having them on the left hand side (called Yoda style) reduces coding errors in languages where you are allowed to use assignment operator inside a conditional and you unintentionally mistyped the comparison operator `==` as a single `=`:

```
// What you intended to write
if (a == 6) ...
// What you wrote instead
if (a = 6) ... // --> always true as the value of a is changed to 6
// What if Yoda style is used
if (6 = a) ... // --> compile time error
```

Comment: This is not the only reason, when comparing to null. In some cases, it can prevent overloaded == operator to fall into an infinite loop when they are miscoded, especially if the class is from a third-party library that you cannot 100% trust.

Answer (score 15):

### What

It's a coding style in use for languages with many implicit type conversions (friendly named Yoda from Star Wars character because of his [OSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93subject%E2%80%93verb) word order). Sometimes it's even enforced and required by project guide-lines to prevent some kind of errors derived from typos. Different languages have different *variations* and extensions of this style but I'll limit this answer to C and C#.

### Why Yes

For example in C you can write:

```
int a = CalculateValue();
if (a = CalculateAnotherValue()) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

This code will assign to `a` the value returned from `CalculateValue()` then it'll overwrite the value with the result of `CalculateAnotherValue()` and if it's not zero then it'll execute the code. Probably it's not what intended to do and the assignment in the `if` expression is a mistake. From your example with `NULL` then you may have:

```
if (pBuffer = NULL)
```

Again probably it's not what you want (and it's a quite common mistake), you'll assign NULL to the pointer and the condition will be always false. If you write:

```
if (NULL = pBuffer)
```

It won't compile (because you can't assign a value to a literal) and you'll get a compile-time error.

This kind of compile time checks are not the only reason to use this coding style, look this C# (very common) code:

```
if (text != null && text.Equals("something", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    DoSomething();
```

It could be contracted to:

```
if ("something".Equals(text, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    DoSomething();
```

### Why No

In C# *usually* it doesn't matter. It's a practice *inherited* from C/C++. Because in C# expressions are not converted automatically to `bool` then following code won't compile:

```
if (Request.QueryString["PartnerID"] = null)
```

Then this practice is useless in C# (with the exception pointed out by @IlianPinzon in the comments), nothing about performance it was used only to avoid such kind of mistakes.

About the last example in the *Why yes* section the problem is readability, to write `"something".Equals(text)` is like to say "if happy is the guy" instead of "if the guy is happy".

### Performance

Starting from these functions:

```
static bool TestRight(object value)
{ return value == null; }

static bool TestLeft(object value)
{ return null == value; }
```

They produce following IL:

```
.maxstack 2
.locals init ([0] bool CS$1$0000)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldnull 
L_0002: ldarg.0 
L_0003: ceq 
L_0005: stloc.0 
L_0006: br.s L_0008
L_0008: ldloc.0 
L_0009: ret
```

The only difference is in lines L_0001 and L_0002, they're just swapped but order of its operands doesn't change the behavior of `ceq`. Even if you override `Equals()` method the JIT compiler will produce the same assembly code for both expressions (because the comparison will be always done by `Equals()`, `null` is *typeless*).

Things can be more complicated if the comparison involves a user defined equality comparer, in this case there is not a rule and it'll depend on the effective `op_Equals` implementation. For example this `==` implementation:

```
public static bool operator==(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
        return true;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        return false;

    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

In this case if the first operand is `null` the execution will be slightly faster (because `MyType.Equals()` won't be even called) but this performance gain is very small: you save one comparison, few jumps and a virtual function call. Moreover you can rewrite the function to be faster in the opposite case (in case you really matter about this).

Here a small test where `MyType.Equals(object)` simply returns `true` for any non `null` parameter. The test will be looped `Int32.MaxValue` times:

```
Operation       Total time (ms)
lhs == null               10521
null == lhs                2346
```

It seems the "optimized" version that avoid unnecessary call to `Equals()` is five times faster but note that the loop count is very high and actual implementation of `Equals()` is empty, a true implementation will reduce the relative overhead of the function call (and probably you'll have something else than this **micro-optimization** to do). For system classes you can't rely on this details, for example `String.Equals()` will be always called by operators (no matters the order) but you can't assume one code path is faster and this fact won't change in future versions of the framework (or for different CPU architectures).

Comment: I'm curious, have heard of it but I'm not familiar with C/C++. Why was it common to have the constant on the left side?

Comment: @Adriano: There's one scenario, where you can still get bitten by it in C# though. Try replacing `int` with `bool`. But yeah, Yoda conditions are out of fashion in C#.

Comment: @IlianPinzon you're right, with bool it has sense but...I did dislike this so much because of readability (personal taste, I know) that I'm ready to pay the price :)

Comment: @Matten I added some examples.

Comment: @Matten - the convention was to always put the constant on the left hand side of the expression so that an error would be statically detected at compile time in the event of a typo in which = (assignment) was coded instead of the intended == (equality comparison). OK now I see this has already been answered in the question. Too late.

Comment: +1 for the remark about user overloaded comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of style. Someone prefers to write

```
if (N == var) ...
```

just because if you missed one `=` (common case for beginners)

```
if (N = var)
```

where `N` is constant, compiler will give an error.

In case of

```
if (var = N)
```

it may give you a warning and may not (depends on compiler and flags). So sometimes it's hard enough to find where the problem is.

The performance of both variants are the same. Choose your style and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

`Constant [Operator] Actual Value` is known as [Yoda Conditions](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions) because it is like "if it is the blue – this is the sky" or "if that is tall – this is a man."

Usage of this conditions style was popular on C/C++ where you could assign value to variable when typed `=` instead of `==`. In C# it makes no sense to use Yoda Conditions.

Also I have doubts it has better performance. Even if it has some performance benefit, it will be extremely small. Match smaller than readability drawbacks.