# Simple bool flip in a countdown

Tags: c#, boolean, counter

I'm an absolute beginner programmer and am learning C# using visual studio 2012.

I have created a small form program that involves a counter. I would like the background to change color for each tick, but I cannot understand why my code doesn't work. The color changes once and then stays that way. I must be making a fundamental mistake.

Can anyone see what this issue is?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    int timeLeft = 60;
    bool metronome = true;

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        if (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
            timeLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(timeLeft);
            Metronome();
        }
        else
        {
            // Stop the timer
            timer1.Stop();                
        }
    }


    public void Metronome()
    {
        metronome = !metronome;
        if (metronome = true)
                {
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
                }
        else
                {
                    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
    }
```

Comment: Surely `if (metronome = true)` should be `if (metronome == true)`?
Or even `if (metronome)`.

Comment: So unlucky, the only scenario [YODA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10811421/1207195) is useful in C#...

Answer (score 6):

You have made a mistake with the condition:

```
if (metronome = true)
```

You are using here [the assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). So what are you simply doing is setting a `true` to the `metronome` and then value of `metronome` is always `true`. It should be [the equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx):

```
if (metronome == true)
```

or simply better:

```
if (metronome)
```

Comment: Facepalm! Thanks Konrad. That's obviously it. Works correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

`if (metronome = true)`

First `metronome = true` sets `metronome` to `true`, and then it examines the value of that whole expression, which is `true` in the `if`  and does what that says.

C# makes it harder to make this mistake that other C-style languages (because a lot of assignments that get cast to `true` or `false` in an `if` in those languages, C# just refuses to deal with), but it can still happen with `bool`s.

What you probably wanted was `if (metronome == true)`.

More idiomatic, and harder to make this mistake with if its your habit, is `if (metronome)`.

There should have been a warning when you compiled, like:

> warning CS0665: Assignment in conditional expression is always constant. Did you mean to use `==' instead ?

Always look at those warnings, and look them up if you're confused (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sde1ax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx is about that error).

Warnings are different to errors because there can sometimes be some strange reason why we really want to do the thing warned about, rather than errors that are just nonsense to the compiler or clearly bad ideas, but they're always worth checking, especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: Yes it looks like the warning was there. TBH I hadn't been paying much attention to warnings because they didn't stop the program running. Rookie mistake.

Comment: Rookies need to pay the most attention to warnings. You can disable warnings whether for a whole project (I'd say to never do that, myself) or in one spot, but if you don't know exactly why it's okay to disable a particular warning in a particular place you're just playing ostrich; that's for managers and politicians, not craftspeople like programmers. I personally have a policy that I never disable a warning without a comment explaining why, partly for when reading it, and partly because if I can't explain succinctly why disabling's a good idea, then it isn't!

Comment: But that's for down the line when you can know the rules well enough to know when to bend them, like poetic license for hacking. Code expresses your intent and approach as well as telling the computer what to do, and `#pragma warning disable` carries with it an implication of "stand back, I'm an expert at this bit", so don't use it until you can say that with a straight face ;) In the meantime, examine every warning even more closely than errors.

Answer (score 1):

Surely `if (metronome = true)` should be `if (metronome == true)`?
Or even `if (metronome)`. Also, when your code doesn't work as expected, it help to put [Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your code so that you can debug it. You could for instance put one in your `Metronome` method and step through the code, checking the values and seeing what is *actually* going on.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan. Just had a play with breakpoints. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is all said regarding your typo. :) However, I like to add, that you even could have used the accidental assignment for toggling the color itself. A one-liner:

```
public void Metronome()
{
    this.BackColor = (metronome = !metronome) ? Color.Crimson : Color.Black;
}
```

If the toggle-variable `metronome` is `false` in the beginning, the first call would assign `Color.Crimson`, the second `Color.Black`, ... This is due to the fact, that the expression "assignment of a variable" evaluates to the assigned value itself. So at first `metronome` switches to `true` and therefore the whole expression is `true`, so `Color.Crimson` is assigned.

Btw, thats the reason why you can write the following (assigning 5 to `a` and `b`):

```
int a, b;
a = b = 5;
```

---

I use a variation of this (also a combination of toggling and checking) e.g. in setters or short methods that set a variable to execute a function or to raise an event on change of the value. (This works because the expressions are evaluated from left to right.)

```
private bool aValue;
public void SetIt() 
{ 
    if (aValue != (aValue = true)) 
      onSet(); // do something on change to true
}
public void UnsetIt() 
{ 
    if (aValue != (aValue = false))
      onUnset();  // do something on change to false
}
```